# Is /home directory in root partition mapped to /home partition

Tags: filesystems

My `/home` partition is on `/dev/sda1`. My `/` partition is on `/dev/sda2`.

Whenever I make a file in `/home` partition it shows up in `/` partition under the `/home` directory.

The Windows equivalent is to make a file on the D drive and the file is also visible on C drive.

How is this possible ?

Comment: This is the philosophy of UNIX/Linux filesystems. And even in Windows you can mount disk D to appear as directory to disc C

Comment: Kernel will record all the mounts, when you access some path, it will calculate which filesystem you're accessing and do operation on it. See /proc/self/mountinfo

Comment: Windows Also use similar structure, except Win32 doesn't expose the same API

Answer (score 3):

If your filesystem experience today is based in Windows, or single disk/partition systems, then you may not be used to the concept of mountpoints.  (though Windows now supports mounting disks at a mount path now, too, it's not as common there as in Linux/Unix)

Your filesystem in Linux/Unix is a nested hierarchy of files. (folders are files, too..)

You start with `/`.  The root of everything.  In your case, this is on partition `/dev/sda2`.  With `/home` on `/dev/sda1`, you end up with

- `/`

  - `dev/`

    - `pts/`
    - (stuff)
  - `sys/`
  - `home/`

    - `rebecca/`

      - `txtfile.txt`
    - `bob/`

etc.  (there are a lot more directories, this is just an example)

So, the path from `/` -> `/home/rebecca/textfile.txt` is intended to be as transparent as possible.  So, while it appears that `textfile.txt` is in the `/` partition, it's actually not.  It's in the `/home/` partition.  It's just that *that* partition is `mounted` in the `/` directory as `/home`.

Try these three commands:

- `df /`
- `df /home/`
- `df /home/rebecca/textfile.txt`  <-- use a real path to a file

The `df` command will show you all your filesystems, real and virtual, that are mounted on your system at the time you run the command.  Using `df` as I have in the examples above serves to filter the output to allow you to examine fewer things at a time.

---

**TL;DR** - it's how Unix and Linux mountpoints work to make all your various disks appear together to be a single cohesive file and directory tree.

Answer (score 2):

In a POSIX filesystem, *everything* exists somewhere inside of the root of the filesystem, located at `/`.  On your root partition, which you have mounted at `/`, you have a directory, `/home`.  This directory is (presumably) being used as a *mount point* (i. e. the location at which a mounted filesystem such as a partition resides) for the `home` partition.  Files created there *are* being created in the `home` partition, the contents of which are visible at that partition's mount point.

Notwithstanding the issues caused by making the contents of `/home` disappear, if you were to:

```
# umount /home; mount /dev/sda1 /mnt; ls /mnt
```

You would see the contents of what *had* been in `/home`, now visible at `/mnt`.

Don't actually do this; this is a demonstrative thought-experiment.

You can see a list of which filesystems are mounted at which mount points by observing the output of the `mount` command when given no parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The filesystem (partition) containing your own files can be placed anywhere in the filesystem tree, which starts as `/`. Typically it's placed at `/home` and you have a directory in it that is named as your username. For example, you might have `/home/rebecca`.

UNIX-based systems (including Linux-based ones) use a single rooted filesystem (`/`). Windows systems use a multi-rooted filesystem (`C:`, `D:`, etc.).

When you write a file to a location you usually don't need to worry about which partition it's being written to, as long as there is enough disk space to hold the file's content.